# How to make hash password if import excel laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How to make hash password in the model laravel 5.1? any idea?

```html
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Members extends Model {

 //
 protected $fillable =  ['id', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'status_members'];
 protected $table = 'members';
}
```

Comment: Password hash from what and for what?

Comment: i want to import data excel, it work but, password not to be hash,

Comment: I don't see how the code provided has anything to do with your last message. Also, you didn't answer the 2nd part of the question.

Comment: please provide the code where you are importing excel data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Put this in your model class

public function setPasswordAttribute($value){

    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

This will hash the value everytime to send a password to the model.

As for the excel side of things please update your question with the current code you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much